# InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread

Tags: mysql, sql, database, crash

I would like to ask your support to solve my problem, I have a server in mysql which suffered a download, to ignite I realize that the MySQL service had died.

When you want to start it simply mark the following error in console.

```
Job failed to start
```

Reviewing the mysql error.log file here is what it shows:

```
170411 11:11:30 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170411 11:11:30 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170411 11:11:30 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170411 11:11:30 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
170411 11:11:30 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170411 11:11:30 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170411 11:11:30 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is F6B400
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
170411 11:11:32  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id F6B22B, 1 rows to undo
170411 11:11:32  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
170411 11:11:32  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2791775040 in file     fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >= FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:11:32 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346075 K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb72f0a43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x484)[0xb719cfa4]
[0xb6e50400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5cb933)[0xb743e933]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5490e7)[0xb73bc0e7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x55f4c2)[0xb73d24c2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x556c54)[0xb73c9c54]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x558093)[0xb73cb093]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5510ba)[0xb73c40ba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x610f7a)[0xb7483f7a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x611524)[0xb7484524]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551645)[0xb73c4645]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551d19)[0xb73c4d19]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb6dc9d4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb6bd8ace]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
170411 11:11:32 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170411 11:11:32 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170411 11:11:32 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170411 11:11:32 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
170411 11:11:32 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170411 11:11:32 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170411 11:11:32 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is F6B400
170411 11:11:32  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
170411 11:11:32  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id F6B22B, 1 rows to undo
170411 11:11:32  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2791775040 in file     fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >=     FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:11:32 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346075     K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb731ca43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x484)[0xb71c8fa4]
[0xb6e7c400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5cb933)[0xb746a933]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5490e7)[0xb73e80e7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x55f4c2)[0xb73fe4c2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x556c54)[0xb73f5c54]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x558093)[0xb73f7093]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5510ba)[0xb73f00ba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x610f7a)[0xb74aff7a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x611524)[0xb74b0524]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551645)[0xb73f0645]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551d19)[0xb73f0d19]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb6df5d4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb6c04ace]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
170411 11:11:33 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
170411 11:11:33 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
170411 11:11:33 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
170411 11:11:33 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
170411 11:11:33 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
170411 11:11:33 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
170411 11:11:33 InnoDB: highest supported file format is Barracuda.
InnoDB: 1 transaction(s) which must be rolled back or cleaned up
InnoDB: in total 1 row operations to undo
InnoDB: Trx id counter is F6B400
170411 11:11:33  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
InnoDB: Starting in background the rollback of uncommitted transactions
170411 11:11:33  InnoDB: Rolling back trx with id F6B22B, 1 rows to undo
170411 11:11:33  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 2791775040 in file     fut0lst.ic line 83
InnoDB: Failing assertion: addr.page == FIL_NULL || addr.boffset >=     FIL_PAGE_DATA
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
16:11:33 UTC - mysqld got signal 6 ;
This could be because you hit a bug. It is also possible that this binary
or one of the libraries it was linked against is corrupt, improperly built,
or misconfigured. This error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
We will try our best to scrape up some info that will hopefully help
diagnose the problem, but since we have already crashed,
something is definitely wrong and this may fail.

key_buffer_size=16777216
read_buffer_size=131072
max_used_connections=0
max_threads=151
thread_count=0
connection_count=0
It is possible that mysqld could use up to
key_buffer_size + (read_buffer_size + sort_buffer_size)*max_threads = 346075     K  bytes of memory
Hope that's ok; if not, decrease some variables in the equation.

Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x30000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace+0x33)[0xb72c5a43]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x484)[0xb7171fa4]
[0xb6e25400]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5cb933)[0xb7413933]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5490e7)[0xb73910e7]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x55f4c2)[0xb73a74c2]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x556c54)[0xb739ec54]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x558093)[0xb73a0093]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x5510ba)[0xb73990ba]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x610f7a)[0xb7458f7a]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x611524)[0xb7459524]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551645)[0xb7399645]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x551d19)[0xb7399d19]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x6d4c)[0xb6d9ed4c]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(clone+0x5e)[0xb6badace]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
```

I would like to have your help, sorry if it is obvious the error in the log but I am not an expert in servers I only have a little knowledge.

Comment: Did you do what it says and check [this page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html) for recovery details? The fact that you have a corrupt database is apparent based on logs.

Comment: Try innodb_force_recovery until its value of 3, my service starts but when trying to connect send this error  **Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
**